# How do I create a C program that stores the names of 5 animals and prints the memory address when the user chooses any of them?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

```
//The following program obtains the memory address of one of the 5 animal names entered by the user.

#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    const char* x[5]={"Lion","Tiger","Jaguar","Cheetah","Puma"};

    //It is clear that &x[0]is equivalent toX. And, x[0]is equivalent to *x.

    int i; //Basically, &x[i]is equivalent to x+i and x[i]is equivalent to *(x+i).
    int *p;


    printf("Write the name of an animal: "); 
    for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        printf("The address of the chosen animal is:[%d] = %p\n", i, x[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is what I have, except that I need the program to ask for a single name of an animal so that it can give its memory address because the program ask me for the name of an animal but no matter what I write, it immediately generates the addresses of the 5 names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that's really needed for your program is a `scanf` call to read input from the user.  Then use `strcmp` to compare the string the user typed with the strings in your `x` array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>         // add this include for strcmp

int main() {
    const char* x[5] = { "Lion","Tiger","Jaguar","Cheetah","Puma" };

    char inputArray[21]; // 20 + 1 for null char

    int i;

    printf("Write the name of an animal: ");
    scanf("%20s", inputArray);

    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        if (strcmp(inputArray, x[i]) == 0) {
            printf("The address of the chosen animal is:[%d] = %p. The animal chosen was %s\n", i, x[i], x[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I took the liberty of extending your printf to include the name of the animal selected. Not just the address.

And the `p` variable wasn't getting used at all, so I removed it.

The `strcmp` call will compare the contents of what the user typed (all chars up to the trailing with the chars in x[i] until a null char is hit in either. If no differences encountered, strcmp will return 0.

If you want to support case insensitive compares to support the user typing `LION` or `lion` and still matching `Lion`, that's an exercise I'll leave for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, and excelent explanation.